# sustituir una cadena por otra entre corchetes dentro de una variable C#

Tags: c#

Tengo una variable con un valor que tiene que sustituir a un trozo de cadena que esta entre {} en otra variable de tipo string.

Tengo la variable idUno que sustituira un trozo de cadena por su valor:

```
string idUno = "1234";
string cadenaInicial = "La id:{idUno} esta iniciada."
string cadenaFinal = $"" + cadenaInicial;
```

El resultado de cadenaFinal es: La id:{idUno} esta iniciada.

El resultado que busco de cadenaFinal es: La id 1234 esta iniciada.

Comment: Puedes usar String.Replace para tal fin, tienes la documentación en https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0

Comment: Si con string.Replace funcionaria pero me gustaria hacerlo usando $ porque se puede dar el caso que tenga varias cadenas a cambiar

Comment: Si quieres usar la interpolación, el simbolo $ tiene que estar en la cadena en la que esta la variable, si no obviamente lo toma como un texto. Asi que sería `$"La id:{idUno} esta iniciada."` no pudes insertar el `$` despues. La cuestion es que la interpolación de cadenas se realiza en tiempo de compilación, no de ejecucion.

Answer (score 1):

Para "interpolar cadenas" (es el termino correcto) se utiliza como [prefijo de la cadena el signo $](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation)

En tu ejemplo

```
string idUno = "1234";
string cadenaFinal = $"La id:{idUno} esta iniciada."
```

Pero si necesitas algo de tener como un template, no te podras utilizar interpolacion sino mas bien String.Format

```
private const string TEMPLATE = "La id:{0} esta iniciada.";

string cadenaFinal3 = String.Format(TEMPLATE, idUno);
```

Si bien necesitas algo "mas especial" se deberia crear algo mas personalizado o ver si te sirve crear tu propio [FormattableString](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.formattablestring?view=net-7.0)

Enlaces que te pueden servir de ayuda o guia

- [Interpolacion de cadenas en C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation)
- [Interpolacion de cadenas mediante $](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: La opcion del template es buena pero no puedo poner {0} ya que tiene que ser {idUno} porque recibo esta cadena como respuesta de un servicio.

Comment: La ironía... "'*interlopar* cadenas' es el término correcto"... Querrás decir, *interpolar*?

Comment: Gracias Ariel. Corregido.